# Google Sheets API javascript quickstart uses obsolete Google Sign-in Platform Library, how can I use Google Identity Services library

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-js-client

Is there a modern version of the quickstart?

[Google sheets javascript quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js)

Using google's code will display their own error in the browser console:

> Your client application uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information.

Comment: To begin with cross post this over on [google-api-js-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client)  they should know there are samples out of date.   Im going to see if i can find a google drive dev rel to ping.

Comment: Found a dev rel they said that the new samples are on the way but did not give me any time frame.